# Magento 2: transparent plane/square through image

Tags: magento2, product-images, image-upload

Whenever I upload an image via Magento it places a transparent plane within the image or it covers the entire image. 
My guess is that this happens with resizing or caching the image, but I have no clue how to find this. 
In the pictures below it becomes quite clear what happens:
[image: Transparent plane through image]
[image: Fully 'greyed' image]
Any ideas on where the problem might be?

Comment: There is an option for watermark, perhaps it needs to be disabled? [link](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-upload-image-watermarks-in-magento-2.html)